# Subdomains not working using express-vhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, digital-ocean, express-vhost

new to Stack Overflow.

So I'm hosting my website using Express (Node 9) on a Digital Ocean droplet. I'm using `express-vhost` so I can detect subdomains to allow me to do `api.example.com` instead of `example.com/api` but when I try it, it just directs me to `example.com` while still having the `api.` part in the hostname.

I'm not sure if this is a programming problem or if it's actually something to do with my DNS records or maybe Digital Ocean is the problem. I'm not well equipped with knowledge of VPSes and hosting.

Here's the code:

```
// app.js
var subdomain = require('express-vhost');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var api = require("./api.js")

subdomain.register('api.localhost:3000', api)
app.use(subdomain.vhost(app.enabled('trust proxy')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Detect Region and send to correct subdomain!');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and the other file

```
// api.js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("api url")
});

module.exports = router;
```

Sorry if this isn't enough information. Happy to answer any other questions you need answered.

-- sys

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to use `express-vhost` (old and deprecated package) but directly the `vhost` module of the express org.

```
const vhost = require('vhost')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const api = require('./api')

app.enable('trust proxy')

app.use(vhost('api.localhost:8000', api)) // api being your router

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Detect Region and send to correct subdomain!');
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: I tried this on both localhost and my webserver and it didn't seem to work. I used lvh.me so localhost could pick up subdomains.